# How fast does this grow with $t$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, asymptotics

What is a good asymptotic for $$\frac1{1-\frac1{\zeta(2)}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac1t\rfloor}\frac{1-it(1-\ln(it))}{i^2}}?$$

Comment: When you say holds over $\mathbb{Z}$, do you mean there simply exists at least one pair $a, b$ or something stronger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better way is to say "how fast this grows with $1/t$"? Let $A=\lfloor 1/t \rfloor$, and consider the sum
$$\widetilde S = \sum_{i=1}^A
 \left( \frac 1 {i^2} - \frac {\ln A + 1} {A i} + \frac {\ln i} {A i} \right).$$
It is sufficient to use the estimate
$$ I_A + C \leq S_A \leq I_A + C + f(A), \\
S_A = \sum_{i=1}^A f(i), I_A=\int_1^A f(i) di, \\
C = \lim_{A \to \infty} ( S_A - I_A ),$$
which holds for $f$ monotonically decreasing to zero. Applying this estimate to each term in $\widetilde S$ gives
$$\widetilde S = \frac {\pi^2} 6 - \frac {\ln^2 A} {2 A} -
 \frac{(\gamma + 1) \ln A} {A} - \frac{ \gamma - \gamma_1 + 1} A +
 O \left( \frac {\ln A} {A^2} \right),$$
$\gamma$ is Euler's constant, and
$$\gamma_1 = \lim_{A \to \infty} \left(
 \sum_{i=1}^A \frac {\ln i} i -  \int_1^A \frac {\ln i} i di \right)$$
is the first Stieltjes constant.

The summand in your sum $S$ has $A + \{1/t\}$ instead of $A$; the difference $S - \widetilde S$ can be estimated in the same way and turns out to be $O(A^{-2} \ln^2 A)$, so only the $O$ term in $\widetilde S$ needs to be adjusted to get an estimate for $S$. Now
$$\frac 1 {1 - \frac 6 {\pi ^2} S} =
\frac {\pi ^2 A} {3 \ln(A) (\ln A + 2 \gamma + 2) +
 6(\gamma - \gamma_1 + 1)} + O \left( \frac 1 {\ln A} \right).$$
The leading term is given by 
$$ \frac 1 {1 - \frac 6 {\pi ^2} S} \sim \frac {\pi^2 A} {3 \ln^2 A}.$$
If we assume $\{1/t\}=0$, then the error term can be improved because the terms in $\widetilde S$ that were estimated separately are not independent, and $O(A^{-2} \ln A)$ in $\widetilde S$ is in fact a weak estimate.